# Calling a function in Viewholder when item selected using SnapHelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a horizontal Recycler view implemented with SnapHelper to get a carousal effect. In my ViewHolder I have a function to animate the views inside Recycler item. So whenever an item is scrolled to center (selected) in SnapHelper I need to start the animation. I have tried following code but its not working. Sometimes I am getting viewholder as null.

```
widgetScrollView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {

                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int pos = ((LinearLayoutManager) widgetScrollView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                        ResultTallyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = (ResultTallyAdapter.ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos);
                        viewHolder.startAnimation(MainActivity.this, pos);
                    }
                }, 1000);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying same thing like you. But code is different. I use `SnapHelper` to find current view and get position from this view and start operation on adapter by this position. You can get idea following code, may help you

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            synchronized (this) {
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    //calculatePositionAndScroll(recyclerView);

                    View view = snapHelper.findSnapView(recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
                    if (view != null) {
                        int pos = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().getPosition(view);
                        Log.d("RecyclerViewTest", "position: " + pos + "  item: " + itemList.get(pos).getName());

                        makeSelectedItem(pos); // do your stuff on this view
                       // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }
    });
```